# Is it okay to ask time-dependent questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I thought about asking something like "Where can I watch World Chess Championship 2021?" or "Who will stream WCC 2021?" and I really liked the question. But then I realized that it will be no longer useful question after WCC ends. My intuition says do not ask something like this but I also wanted to ask here with generalizing it:

Is it okay to ask questions which are related to future but after a while it will not make sense?

Comment: Yes, questions like that are fine!

Comment: For exactly this fear I did not ask a computerchess related question, which are the worst offender :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, questions like that are indeed accepted. They are not inherently useless, as they may provide valuable data for a researcher later on. There may be a caveat though if the question is to obscure or difficult to answer, but your example questions are nowhere near.